# how to format this text file

Tags: php, shell

I have a text file with content like this

```
   customer-1 Product-2
   customer-1 Product-3
   customer-1 Product-7
   customer-2 Product-20
   customer-2 Product-12
   ...
```

I'd like to format it like

```
  customer-1 Product-2, Product-3, Product-7, Product-20
  customer-2 Product-20, Product-12
  ...
```

How to do it in shell script or php?

Thank you

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i am looking for a one-line or something. still thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pipe your file to this awk script. Will have one extra line in BOF, if you need to remove it, use 'head'.

```
awk 'BEGIN { one = ""; } { if ( one != $1 ) { printf("\n%s %s",$1,$2); one = $1; } else { printf(" %s",$2); } } END { printf("\n"); }'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP:

1. get the contents of your text file using `file_get_contents()`
2. `explode()` the resulting string on each newline `\n`
3. loop through the resulting array and `explode()` on each space

You'll then have your data loaded into a multi-dimensional array and can loop through to get it into the format you require.

**Added code example (not tested):**

```
$file = file_get_contents('../path/to/file.txt');
$rows = explode('\n', $file);

$customers = array();

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $rowPieces = explode(' ',$row);
    $customers[$rowPieces[0]][] = $rowPieces[1];
}

foreach($customers as $c => $products) {
    $customers[$c] = implode(', ',$products);
}

echo implode('\n', $customers);
```

Comment: If your data might contain inconsistencies (double spaces, etc) @Jack's solution using preg_match might be more reliable. But this is really just to give you an idea rather than a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could break it down:

- load the contents
- for every line, find the customer and product
- group the products per customer
- output

For example:

```
// preg_match_all will find all "customer-" (digits) and "product-" (digits)
if (preg_match_all('/(customer-\d+)\s*(product-\d+)/i', $s, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
        $purchases = array();
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
                // $match[1] contains customer id
                // $match[2] contains product id
                $purchases[$match[1]][] = $match[2];
        }
        // $purchases now contains a list of products, grouped by customer
        foreach ($purchases as $customer => $products) {
                echo $customer, ' ', join(', ', $products), PHP_EOL;
        }
}
```